# How to verify this statement

Tags: complex-analysis

The question asked to verify this statement. I really dont know where to start and it will be a great help if someone can solve it

$z=r e^{i\theta}$, $r<1$

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int \frac{f(e^{i t}) e^{i t}}{e^{i t} - z} dt = f(z)
$$

Comment: Please check my edit, I'm not sure I got the correct formulas.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int _0^{2\pi}\frac{f(e^{i t}) e^{i t}}{e^{i t} - z} dt = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(e^{i t})\cdot i\cdot e^{i t}}{e^{i t} - z} dt =$$
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(\zeta ) }{\zeta - z} d\zeta = f(z)$$ by Cauchy formula, where $\gamma $ is the circle $|z|=1$